# Excel average sum using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a CSV file with 3 columns:

```
Value0  Value1  Value2  Value3
Test1   2.43    0         2
Test2   1.5 0   1         5
Test3   18.12   0.1       1
Test4   7.99    0         2
Test5   3.84    0.1       2
```

What I would like to do is find the average of Value 1, 2 and 3 and write them in the csv file using powershell.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: I havn't really been able to find a proper solution. I'm not that big of a powershell wiz :(

Comment: Well, you need to try _something_. Otherwise I recommend
http://www.rent-acoder.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short of it would be something along these lines:

```
# Import the CSV file into an object
$data = import-csv filename.csv

# Add a new column to hold the averages
$data = $data|Select *,Average

# Iterate through the object, get the average from each row and assign to the added column
ForEach ($row in $data) {
$row.Average = $data.Value1, $data.Value2, $data.Value3|measure -Average|Select -expand Average
}

# Export back out to a CSV
$data|Export-csv outputfilename.csv -NoType
```